# Django - Make a related queryset for a set of foreignkeys

Tags: django-views, django-queryset

Hi I am trying to write a view, so that I can display all Items related to a Bill. How do I have to write my query? The query **bills** returns a QuerySet[bill1, bill2]. Thought I can get a related queryset, so I can access every item of a bill.

If I do a for-loop now in my HTML I have all items listed for both bills no the one they relate to.

The models.py looks like this:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    date = models.DateField()

class Item(models.Model):
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill)
    registration = models.OneToOneField(Registration, unique=True)
```

I wrote a view:

```
def payments(request):
    customer = Team.objects.get(owner=request.user) # Gets the right user
    bills = customer.bill_set.all()                 # Query all bills of the user

    items = bills.item_set.all()     # Tried but doesnt work

    context = {'bills': bills,
               'items': items,
               'customer': customer,}
    return render(request, 'payment/payments.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [**in** field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in). The code would be this simple:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(bill__in=bills)
```

Where `bills` is your `Bill` queryset.